# HSQL DB in Servlet: lock file not released

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, hsqldb

I am running a HSQLDB inside a Servlet. When I redeploy the application to the web server the .lck file is not properly released and the HSQL server cannot load the file.

Web server is Tomcat 7.0.22 shipped with NetBeans...

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is the init code:

```
@Override public void init() throws ServletException {
        HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();
        p.setProperty("server.database.0", dbPath);
        p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", Environment.PERSISTENCE_HSQL_DB_NAME);
        p.setProperty("server.port", Environment.PERSISTENCE_HSQL_PORT);
        server = new Server();
        server.setProperties(p);
        server.setSilent(false);
        server.setTrace(true);
        server.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
        server.setErrWriter(null);
        server.start();

        server.checkRunning(true);

        /* Exception handling */
    }
```

Here is my shutdown / destroy method:

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    server.setNoSystemExit(true);
    server.stop();
    server.shutdown();
    controller.shutdown();
}
```

I am using JPA. If the database loads (first start) the app is working fine. Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="embedded_hsql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- Entities -->
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/fst_db;hsqldb.lock_file=false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SA"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
        <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I added "hsqldb.lock_file=false" for testing purposes which has no effect at all. In general I don't want to disable file locking...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access that database from within the same web-application than it would be better to :

1. run HSQLDB in ["in-process"](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess) mode.
2. define database as Tomcat's [resource](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/context.html#Resource%20Definitions) and access it with JNDI.

That would help to get rid of that hsqldb start/stop burden completely.

Comment: Can you give me more details for that solution? What would my persistence.xml look like? And if I define the resource and have to tell where the actual HSQL file would be. I still have to problem of dynamically setting the file path...

Comment: HSQLDB databases stored as resources are read-only. See http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi solved the problem this way:

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
    controller.shutdown();
    PersistenceUtility.getInstance().closeAllEntityManagers();

    try {
        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtility.getInstance().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query shutdownQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SHUTDOWN");
        shutdownQuery.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Environment.LOGGER.debug("Database connection closed");
    }

    server.signalCloseAllServerConnections();
    server.shutdown();
    super.destroy();
}
```

My only problem left is that the native query `SHUTDOWN` does the trick but also triggers Exceptions thrown by the corresponding `EntityManager`. My theory is that the database is closed and stopped before the EntityManager has closed its connection...

If I print the stack trace of the catched `Throwable t` I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:58)
    at com.convista.fst.manager.ConfigurationServlet.destroy(ConfigurationServlet.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1764)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5449)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:49)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: connection exception: connection failure: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:169)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection failure: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Do you know what causes this exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

As of HSQLDB 2.4.1, it appears that the proper way to shut down an HSQL server is via the shutdownCatalogs or shutdownWithCatalogs methods of the org.hsqldb.server.Server class.

In your case, this would be:

```
server.shutdownCatalogs(org.hsqldb.Database.CLOSEMODE_NORMAL);
```

One apparent issue with this is that stop() ends up being called when the last database is closed, and then shutdown() is also called which leads to some redundant internal calls, but it doesn't seem harmful.